# Can't install prettytable

Tags: python, pip

I'm unable to "pip install prettytable". What is the best option for installing it?

```
% sudo pip -vvv install prettytable

Downloading/unpacking prettytable
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/ when looking for download links for prettytable
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for prettytable:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/: 404 Client Error: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/prettytable/ when looking for download links for prettytable
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement prettytable
```

Comment: Just download the package and install it manually, perhaps? Or maybe you're looking for `prettytable` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like that prettytable module isn't available on PyPI.
You can download a source code from https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/downloads/list and then install the module.

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PrettyTable/prettytable-0.7.2.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Are you guys talking about `prettyable` or `prettytable`? I'm utterly confused.

Comment: typo, fixed that, it should have been prettytable. the results were originally from that so question and answer are still valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install PrettyTable
```

or

```
pip3 install PrettyTable
```